# How to pass values wrapped in Promise into non-async function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

In a class method, I retrieved some data through an async function, `this.retrieveData()`. This method returns me the data which I intend to pass it to another function called `renderTemplate()`.

```
async getTemplateHtml() {
   const data = await this.retrieveData()
   const html = renderTemplate(`some html template`, {stuff: data}
   return html
}
```

The problem, however, is that `this.retrieveData()` actually returns an array of Promises in the form of `Promise<string>[]` while the signature of `renderTemplate()` is `renderTemplate(string, {stuff: string[]}`

I cannot pass `data` returned from `this.retrieveData()` directly into the `renderTemplate()`'s second parameter because the elements in data are still wrapped in a Promise. I can't change the second parameter of `renderTemplate()` function too because it is from a npm library.

How can I somehow resolve the values wrapped in Promises in `data` so that I can pass it into `renderTemplate()` as its actual value unwrapped from its Promise?

Comment: Does `const data = await Promise.all(this.retrieveData())` do what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `retrieveData` returns an array of promises, it should be:

```
const data = await Promise.all(this.retrieveData());
```

This maps an array of promises to an array of values.

Comment: Just curious, what if `retrieveData()` was returning Promise<string[]> instead? Do I still use Promise.all?

Comment: No, this would be `await this.retrieveData()`, as you originally suggested.